# How to keep edittext focus when click other view or decide whether to change focus status before lose focus?

Tags: java, android-edittext

In my fragment, I have a layout contain several button, and this layout will change format when I focus and lose focus on editText.
here are images:
[image: not focus]

[image: focused]

The problem is when editText is focused, I click those button or try to scroll the layout that contain buttons, editText lose focus directly, this make me can't scroll view also(because layout become not focus status).

And I don't want to use requestFocus at editTexts' onFocusChange, this will make other problem for me(like the soft keyboard will close and open again every time i click button, I want soft keyboard keep open and editText keep focus).

Is there any method to keep my editText focus? thanks.